# content search and sort by number of likes on SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I assumed this one was very straightforward but it is not. The Managed property likes count is set on Sort = NO and it cannot be changed, when used in the content search it delivers and error.

So I took RefinableInt00 and Mapped to ows_likescount (which is sortable). Still it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a re-indexing of the library and now it works